MERN deployment in Vercel
I'm having a difficult time deploying a project in vercel. all my dependencies are correct, installed and updated but I keep getting this error message: Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react/jsx-runtime" from "/vercel/path0/frontend/src/main.js.
I have tried updating my dependencies and installing react jsx runtime and still getting the same error
